# Problem with runnig of Firefox with Selenium on Linux

Tags: python, linux, selenium, firefox

I have a next problem:

I'm using: `Linux version 3.10.0--generic-shared-3.2-20160306 (gcc version 4.9.3 (Gentoo 4.9.3 p1.5, pie-0.6.4))`
Before running of Python file with Selenium, i made a next steps:

1. Create ENV and mkdir fireforx on the bin folder(`.name_env/bin/firefox`)
2. Download Firefox

- download `wget -O FirefoxSetup.tar.bz2 "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=linux64&lang=en-US"`
- unpack to '.name_env/bin/firefox' by `tar jxvf FirefoxSetup.tar.bz2`
- check files on folder `.name_env/bin/firefox` by `ls -al` and saw a next result:

```
    drwxr-x--- 7 name customers      4096 May  3 23:55 .
    drwxr-x--- 4 name customers      4096 May  4 08:40 ..
    -rw-r----- 1 name customers       825 Apr 28 16:50 Throbber-small.gif
    -rw-r----- 1 name customers       891 Apr 28 23:14 application.ini
    drwxr-x--- 4 name customers      4096 May  3 23:55 browser
    -rwxr-x--- 1 name customers    249680 Apr 28 23:54 crashreporter
    -rw-r----- 1 name customers      3902 Apr 28 16:50 crashreporter.ini
    drwxr-x--- 3 name customers      4096 May  3 23:55 defaults
    -rw-r----- 1 name customers       174 Apr 28 23:54 dependentlibs.list
    -rwxr-x--- 1 name customers     14416 Apr 28 23:54 firefox
    -rwxr-x--- 1 name customers    757152 Apr 28 23:54 firefox-bin
    -rw-r----- 1 name customers      1449 Apr 28 23:59 firefox-bin.sig
    -rw-r----- 1 name customers      1449 Apr 28 23:59 firefox.sig
    drwxr-x--- 2 name customers      4096 May  3 23:55 fonts
    drwxr-x--- 3 name customers      4096 May  3 23:55 gmp-clearkey
    drwxr-x--- 2 name customers      4096 May  3 23:55 icons
    -rwxr-x--- 1 name customers    833912 Apr 28 23:54 libfreeblpriv3.so
    -rwxr-x--- 1 name customers    339000 Apr 28 23:54 libipcclientcerts.so
    -rwxr-x--- 1 name customers     43200 Apr 28 23:54 liblgpllibs.so
    -rwxr-x--- 1 name customers   3849656 Apr 28 23:54 libmozavcodec.so
    -rwxr-x--- 1 name customers    228136 Apr 28 23:54 libmozavutil.so
    -rwxr-x--- 1 name customers     14056 Apr 28 23:54 libmozgtk.so
    -rwxr-x--- 1 name customers    117384 Apr 28 23:54 libmozsandbox.so
    -rwxr-x--- 1 name customers   1179208 Apr 28 23:54 libmozsqlite3.so
    -rwxr-x--- 1 name customers     18224 Apr 28 23:54 libmozwayland.so
    -rwxr-x--- 1 name customers    223024 Apr 28 23:54 libnspr4.so
    -rwxr-x--- 1 name customers    711096 Apr 28 23:54 libnss3.so
    -rwxr-x--- 1 name customers    437448 Apr 28 23:54 libnssckbi.so
    -rwxr-x--- 1 name customers    187416 Apr 28 23:54 libnssutil3.so
    -rwxr-x--- 1 name customers     22656 Apr 28 23:54 libplc4.so
    -rwxr-x--- 1 name customers     14376 Apr 28 23:54 libplds4.so
    -rwxr-x--- 1 name customers    163456 Apr 28 23:54 libsmime3.so
    -rwxr-x--- 1 name customers    326088 Apr 28 23:54 libsoftokn3.so
    -rwxr-x--- 1 name customers    414344 Apr 28 23:54 libssl3.so
    -rwxr-x--- 1 name customers 148216472 Apr 28 23:54 libxul.so
    -rw-r----- 1 name customers      1449 Apr 28 23:59 libxul.so.sig
    -rwxr-x--- 1 name customers   1657584 Apr 28 23:54 minidump-analyzer
    -rw-r----- 1 name customers  30226627 Apr 29 00:00 omni.ja
    -rwxr-x--- 1 name customers    806288 Apr 28 23:54 pingsender
    -rw-r----- 1 name customers       165 Apr 28 23:54 platform.ini
    -rwxr-x--- 1 name customers    752976 Apr 28 23:54 plugin-container
    -rw-r----- 1 name customers      1449 Apr 28 23:59 plugin-container.sig
    -rw-r----- 1 name customers      2014 Apr 28 23:59 precomplete
    -rw-r----- 1 name customers         0 Apr 28 23:54 removed-files
    -rw-r----- 1 name customers       132 Apr 28 23:54 update-settings.ini
    -rwxr-x--- 1 name customers     97528 Apr 28 23:54 updater
    -rw-r----- 1 name customers       638 Apr 28 23:54 updater.ini
```

2. Download Geckodriver

- Download: `wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.23.0/geckodriver-v0.23.0-linux64.tar.gz`
- Make a `chmod +x geckodriver`
- Move geckodriver to folder (`.name_env/bin/geckodriver_path`): `mv geckodriver /.name_env/bin/geckodriver_path/`

3. Install a Selenum by Pip: Selenium version = 4.1.3
4. Run a next python script:

```
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options
    import Options as Options_FF from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as Service_FF
    import traceback
    import logging
    ###################################
    logging.basicConfig(level = logging.DEBUG)
    logging.basicConfig(format = '%(process)d-%(levelname)s-%(message)s')
    ################################################
    full_path_linux  = '/.name_env/bin/geckodriver_path'
    options_ff = Options_FF()
    options_ff.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options_ff.add_argument('--headless')
    service_webdriver = Service_FF(executable_path = full_path_linux + 'geckodriver')
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service = service_webdriver, options = options_ff)
    driver.get("https://google.com")
```

And on the console a see this error:

```
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_driver.py", line 68, in <module>
    run_selenium()
  File "test_driver.py", line 53, in run_selenium
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service = service_webdriver, options = options_ff)
  File "/path_to_env/.name_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 176, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/path_to_env/.name_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/path_to_env/.name_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 110, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /path_to_env/.name_env/bin/geckodriver_path/geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

So, pls could you tell me where is a problem?

Additional info:
try to start a bin by `./firefox` and see this problem:

```
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /path_to_env/.name_env/bin/firefox/libmozgtk.so:
libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

Why an archive does not have this file?

Comment: Updated geckodriver to v0.30.0. And have other problem: raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /path_env/.name_env/bin/geckodriver_path/geckodriver

Comment: Close tthis topic. The problem was on a bad installation of Firefox on the Linux